# Send an image with whatsapp using ADB commands

Tags: android, adb, whatsapp

I have no experience with ADB commands , but i would like to send a jpg image to a whatsapp contact using ADB commands. 
I tried to run this command to send a text message and it's working correctly :

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -t text/plain --es android.intent.extra.TEXT "Hello this is a test!" com.whatsapp

However, I am unable to send an image/picture using this command:
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -t image/jpg -e stream "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/download.jpg" com.whatsapp

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

UNLOCK

```
adb shell input keyevent 26 
adb shell input keyevent 82 
adb shell input text [your password]
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

SEND FILE

```
adb shell am start -n com.whatsapp/.Main 
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t  text/plain -e jid 'xxxxxxxxxxx@s.whatsapp.net' --eu android.intent.extra.STREAM file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181025_223214.jpg  -p com.whatsapp
sleep 2
adb shell input tap 990 1800 # SEND BUTTON COORDINATES
```

Comment: Can you please also guide me how to send a normal text message without picture ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send image on whatsapp using adb. max you can do is to automate using any automation framework or use adb input keyevent.

you can push image to gallery your phone or emulator using adb push